# Vue валидация динамическое формы

Tags: javascript, vue.js, валидация

Есть vue, bootstrap-vue и динамическая форма, введенные значения нужно провалидировать. Форма динамическая, т.е. пользователь может добавлять добавлять и удалять поля.

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(input, index) in inputs_hosts_ip">
     <b-input-group>
        <b-form-input type="text" v-model="input.host">
     </b-form-input>
     <b-form-input type="text" v-model="inputs_hosts_ip[index].ip">
     </b-form-input>
     <mu-button small slot="actions" @click="deleteHostIp(index)" class="demo-color-btn" color="#0097a7">отмена</mu-button>
     </b-input-group>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Пробовал добавить vee-validate - одна ошибка дублируется под каждым полем, а так не пойдет. Даже не представляю как зацепиться за уникальные значения полей, чтобы сделать валидацию.

Comment: А чем не устраивает валидация HTML5? Атрибут `pattern` ведь можно биндить по-моему, и в стандарте есть метод для "тихой" проверки (`checkValidity`, если верно помню).

Comment: Там нет сообщений, поэтому отложил как крайний вариант

Comment: *Там нет сообщений* - есть, при этом локализованные [`validationMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Валидация_формы#API_проверки_валидности_HTML5)

Answer (score 0):

у меня это получилось как-то так: https://codepen.io/gleb-shalajkin/pen/qBBYwEq?editors=1010

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      items: [],
      name: 'text'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    creatNewInput(){
      this.items.push({ [this.name]: '' });
    },
    deleteInput(){
      this.items.pop();
    },
    check(){
      //проверка 3 поля
      const input = 2;

      if(this.items[input].text === '') {
        this.items[input].text = 'Чувак, ты не заполнил 3 поле'
        this.$refs[`${this.name}_${input}`][0].style.background = 'red';
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
      <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <input type="text" v-model="item[name]" :ref="name + '_' +index">
      </div>
      
      <button @click="creatNewInput()">Добавить</button>
      <button @click="deleteInput()">Удалить</button>
      <button @click="check()">Проверить</button>
  </div>
```

Так как все свойства vue реактивны, их нужно указывать вначале или задавать с помощью Vue.set(object, propertyName, value). Если у пользователя должна быть возможность создавать сколько угодно инпутов, то как по мне оба эти варианта не очень подходят. Можно сделать одно единственное реактивное свойство(в моем случае это items) и хранить/удалять в нем данные.

Так же обращаться к инпутам можно с помощью ref. Официальная документация: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Comment: так и задумано что консоль выдала ошибку ?

Comment: Я для примера поставил валидацию только для третьего поля, если его нету, то конечно ничего не сработает:)

Answer (score 0):

Так подойдет ?
Вы можете обращаться к модели по индексу и валидировать значения в методе.
Если не получится - пишите :)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    inputs_hosts_ip: [],
    form: [],
  },
  methods: {
    addField(item) {
      this.inputs_hosts_ip.push({
        name: 'input_' + this.inputs_hosts_ip.length,
        type: item
      });
    },
    removeField(index) {
      this.form.splice(index, 1);
      this.inputs_hosts_ip.splice(index, 1);
    },
    validate(e) {
      // validation here
    }
  },
})
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}#app{padding:15px}ul{list-style:none;width:300px}div{margin-top:10px;font-size:12px}label{display:flex;align-items:center}input{border:none;width:100px;height:100%;outline:0;transition:.2s;font-size:16px;margin:10px 0;margin-right:5px}input+button{flex-shrink:0;border:none;background:0 0;font-size:14px;cursor:pointer;outline:0;border:1px dotted #ccc;padding:5px}.type{margin-left:10px}input:focus+button{border-color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(input, index) in inputs_hosts_ip">
      <label>
        <input
           v-model="form[index]"
           :name="input.name"
           :type="input.type"
           class="input"
           :placeholder="input.name"
           @blur="validate"
         >
         <button @click="removeField(index)">Remove</button>
         <span class="type">Type is <kbd>{{ inputs_hosts_ip[index].type }}</kbd></span>
     </label>

    </li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="addField('text')">Add text field</button>
  <button @click="addField('password')">Add password field</button>
  <button @click="addField('email')">Add email field</button>
  <div>
    Array: <kbd>{{ form }}</kbd>
  </div>

</div>
```

**UPD:** Добавил кнопки выбора типа инпута для добавления